# Prove $T^2$ = T if im(T-I) is a subset of ker(T)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be a linear transformation from $R^{2x2}$ to $R^{2x2}$ such that $T^2 = T$, where T is neither the zero transformation nor the identity transformation. I know some values of T, but I want to generally prove that $T^2 = T$ if and only if im(T-I) is a subset of ker(T), where I is the identity transformation. How should I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: HINT: $T^2=T$ if and only if $T^2-T=0$ if and only if $(T-I)T = T(T-I)=0$.

Comment: Tips: when using MathJax, \times as in $\times$ is a better choice to represent the cross than the letter x as in $x$

Answer (score 2):

The statement is true when $T\colon V\to V$ is a linear transformation on the vector space $V$, not just when $V=\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$.

Suppose $T^2=T$; we want to prove that $\operatorname{im}(T-I)\subseteq\ker(T)$. Let $v\in V$ and set $w=(T-I)v=Tv-v$; then
$$
Tw=T(Tv-v)=T^2v-Tv=Tv-Tv=0
$$

Suppose, conversely, that $\operatorname{im}(T-I)\subseteq\ker(T)$. This implies that $T(T-I)$ is the zero map. More generally, if $T_1\colon V\to V$ and $T_2\colon V\to V$ are linear maps, then $\operatorname{im}T_1\subseteq\ker T_2$ if and only if $T_2T_1=0$. Therefore $T^2-T=0$, hence $T^2=T$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b\in im(T-I)\implies \exists ~x\in R^n$such that $(T-I)x=b$.
Now consider$Tb= T(T-I)x=(T^2-T)x= 0$. Hence $Tb=0$. Thus $b \in Nul(T)$. Since $b$ was arbitrary, hence $im(T-I) \subseteq~nul(T)$.
Can you proceed with the converse?